# how to customize the testng reports?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, report, testng

[image: screenshot of testng report]

can you change testng reports aesthetics?like changing the top

```
Test results
1 suite
```

can I change these? I could not find anything usefull at [testng docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-junitreports) .

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your TestNG report using "ReportNG". You can find more details [here](http://reportng.uncommons.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TestNG-XSLT Report generator which uses the default TestNG results output (testng-results.xml). Its uses the pure XSL for report generation and Saxon as an XSL2.0 implementation.

You can find more details at http://seleniumtesting-nx.blogspot.in/2012/03/testng-xslt-report-generation.html